# Small horizontal lines

Tags: horizontal

[image]

How to draw this type of horizontal lines in Latex?

Comment: Make `\frac{}{}` your friend: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\frac` command. If you compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{}{1\mbox{ cube}}\qquad\frac{I\mbox{ cube}\quad J\mbox{
    cube}}{I\times J\mbox{ cube}}\]
\end{document}
```

you will get this:

[image]